# jquery gridster react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gridster

I am trying to wrap jquery.gridster as a react component and getting an error.

'Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).gridster is not a function'

```
import $ from 'jquery';
    componentDidMount() {
            var gridster = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).gridster({
                widget_margins: [5, 5],
                widget_base_dimensions: [150, 150],
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }).data('gridster');
        }
```

I have added script tags to index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.gridster.js" charster="utf-8"></script>
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way, not sure how to import gridster.Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: yes, I use webpack. But wasnt sure how to npm install the particular fork of gridster I wanted, hence downloaded it and tried to refer directly.

Comment: Same issue here, any progress on this? I guess it's related to the plugin loading of jquery in the context of webpack

Answer (score 0):

I'm fine with

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import gridster from 'gridster/dist/jquery.gridster'
```

and in my webpack config

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery"
    })

]
```